# Transform a column of lists based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataset in which the column Dialogue has List of ID:

Frame Name : movie_conversations

```
A   B   Movie   Dialogue
u0  u2  m0      ['L985','L984','L925']
```

and The Mapper to The Dialogue column Dataset looks like this:

Frame Name: conversation_mapping

```
Dialogue_No A   Movie   Name    Dialogue_Str
L985        u0  m0     BIANCA   I hope so.
L984        u2  m0     CAMERON  She okay?
L925        u0  m0     BIANCA   Let's go.
```

I want all the three strings together in a single string and added in a new column in the first dataframe.

so it should look something like this:

```
A   B   Movie   Dialogue               Dialogue_
u0  u2  m0      ['L985','L984','L925'] I hope so.<t>She okay?<t>Let's go.
```

so I thought, let me write a lambda function :

```
movie_conversation.Dialogue_Str = movie_conversation.Dialogue.apply(lambda x : word = list() for index in x word.append(conversations_mapping.loc[conversations_mapping.Dialogue_No == index_,'Dialogue_Str'].iloc[0]))
```

Above code does not work :.

Basically, I want to implement a function like this:

```
index = ['L985','L984','L925']
a = ""
count = 0
for index_ in range(len(index)): 
    if ( len(index)  == count + 1 ):
        a += str(conversations_mapping.loc[conversations_mapping.Dialogue_No == index[index_],'Dialogue_Str'].iloc[0]) 
    else: 
        a += str(conversations_mapping.loc[conversations_mapping.Dialogue_No == index[index_],'Dialogue_Str'].iloc[0]) + '<t>'

    count += 1
```

so should i use lambda function or can implement any other way?

Comment: anyway i can convince you to *not* store sequences in elements of the data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lambda required. Nor apply, for that matter. First, generate a mapping of dialogue numbers to dialogues.

```
dialogue_mapper = dict(
    conversation_mapping[['Dialogue_No', 'Dialogue_Str']].values
)
```

Now, using a list comprehension, replace those lists of dialogue numbers with dialogue strings using `dict.get`.

```
movie_conversations['Dialogue'] = [
    '<t>'.join([dialogue_mapper.get(k) for k in v]) 
    for v in movie_conversations.Dialogue
]
```

---

```
movie_conversations

    A   B Movie                            Dialogue
0  u0  u2    m0  I hope so.<t>She okay?<t>Let's go.
```

Comment: assigning a new column with a dot-operator is iffy at best

Comment: @PaulH It is alright if the column already exists... but that's my bad habit :p

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found. i got this error in the line where the join and mapping is happening..

Comment: The way you wrote the code was very pythonic, can you explain join code which you wrote.

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar you have invalid dialog numbers :( change to .get(k, '')